# How to nest Async Context Managers in Python 3

Tags: python-asyncio

Suppose we had two async context managers that were commonly used together in a nested fashion, but only the result of the second is typically used in the body. For example, if we found ourselves typing this a lot:

```
async with context_mgr_1() as cm1:
    async with cm2.context_mgr_2() as cm2:
        ...do something with cm2...
```

How can we create a single context manager which nests these context managers, so that we can just do:

```
async with context_mgr_2() as cm2:
    ...do something with cm2...
```

contextlib.nested used to accomplish this for non-async context managers, but I have found no such helper in asyncio.

Comment: No way right now.
But you may implement AsyncExitStack following contextlib.ExitStack design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, I've started using this to wrap both synchronous and asynchronous context managers as an asynchronous manager. It allows both AsyncExitStack style push semantics as well as simply wrapping multiple managers.

It is fairly well-tested, but I am not posting the tests or planning on supporting this, so use at your own risk...

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys

from functools import wraps

class AsyncContextManagerChain(object):

    def __init__(self, *managers):
        self.managers = managers
        self.stack = []
        self.values = []

    async def push(self, manager):
        try:
            if hasattr(manager, '__aenter__'):
                value = await manager.__aenter__()
            else:
                value = manager.__enter__()

            self.stack.append(manager)
            self.values.append(value)
            return value
        except:
            # if we encounter an exception somewhere along our enters,
            # we'll stop adding to the stack, and pop everything we've
            # added so far, to simulate what would happen when an inner
            # block raised an exception.
            swallow = await self.__aexit__(*sys.exc_info())
            if not swallow:
                raise

    async def __aenter__(self):
        value = None

        for manager in self.managers:
            value = await self.push(manager)

        return value

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        excChanged = False
        swallow = False # default value
        while self.stack:
            # no matter what the outcome, we want to attempt to call __aexit__ on
            # all context managers
            try:
                swallow = await self._pop(exc_type, exc, tb)
                if swallow:
                    # if we swallow an exception on an inner cm, outer cms would
                    # not receive it at all...
                    exc_type = None
                    exc = None
                    tb = None
            except:
                # if we encounter an exception while exiting, that is the
                # new execption we send upward
                excChanged = True
                (exc_type, exc, tb) = sys.exc_info()
                swallow = False

        if exc is None:
            # when we make it to the end, if exc is None, it was swallowed
            # somewhere along the line, and we've exited everything successfully,
            # so tell python to swallow the exception for real
            return True
        elif excChanged:
            # if the exception has been changed, we need to raise it here
            # because otherwise python will just raise the original exception
            if not swallow:
                raise exc
        else:
            # we have the original exception still, we just let python handle it...
            return swallow

    async def _pop(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
    manager = self.stack.pop()
    if hasattr(manager, '__aexit__'):
        return await manager.__aexit__(exc_type, exc, tb)
    else:
        return manager.__exit__(exc_type, exc, tb)
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Python 3.7 there is [contextlib.AsyncExitStack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.AsyncExitStack):

```py
async with AsyncExitStack() as stack:
    cm1 = await stack.enter_async_context(context_mgr_1())
    cm2 = await stack.enter_async_context(context_mgr_2())
    # ...do something with cm2...
```

It can be used dynamically:

```py
async with AsyncExitStack() as stack:
    connections = [await stack.enter_async_context(get_connection())
        for i in range(5)]
    # All opened connections will automatically be released at the end of
    # the async with statement, even if attempts to open a connection
    # later in the list raise an exception.
```

It inherites [contextlib.ExitStack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) so you can combine async and non-async context managers:

```py
async with AsyncExitStack() as stack:
    cm1 = await stack.enter_async_context(context_mgr_1())
    f = stack.enter_context(open('file.txt'))
    cm2 = await stack.enter_async_context(context_mgr_2())
    # ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to use an ExitStack or AsyncExitStack "transparently", so that end-users don't have to know about the ExitStack API or type all 3 of those lines of code (which is even more typing than the original boilerplate they were trying to avoid)? I think such a solution would answer the original question.

Comment: @shadowtalker I think the whole point of with-blocks, context managers and (Async)ExitStack is that you are able to manage resources explicitly. Do you want to make it transparent? Well, just put the code into destructor (`__del__`). But that’s very fragile. Trust me, we’ve been there :) My previous job coworkers had C++ background so of course they tried to bring RAII (basically resource allocation in constructor, deallocation in destructor) to Python. It did work. Until it broke in some scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Kevin's answer doesn't follow the contextlib.ExitStack impl in 3.5.2 so I've gone ahead and created one based on the official impl in python 3.5.2.  I'll update the impl if I find any issues.

github gist link: https://gist.github.com/thehesiod/b8442ed50e27a23524435a22f10c04a0

Comment: I've updated the impl based on edit suggestions and to also support __enter__/__exit__

Comment: btw coming in 3.7! https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.AsyncExitStack